# Como inserir uma imagem dentro de um arquivo CSS?

Tags: html5, css3, base64, webdesign, data-uri

Utilizo um programa aqui na empresa que em seu módulo Web ele tem sua logo inserida 
diretamente no CSS algo como:

```
#logo img{
  max-width:100%;
  background-image: 'data|base64=acSs....';
}
```

Como faço para eu mesmo criar esse tipo de background?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Essa construção é chamada de [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), é uma maneira de embutir dados em uma página web como se fossem recursos externos.

Segue o formato:

```
data:<MIME-type>;charset=<encoding>;base64,<dados>
```

[Exemplo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Examples):

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

No exemplo `image/png` é o MIME-type; o `charset` foi omitido; e finalmente `base64` indica que o conteúdo está codificado em (adivinhe) [base 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Se omitido o `;base64` é assumido encoding ASCII.*Se não me engano* estes são os únicos encodings permitidos.

---

P.S.:

- Existe uma série de serviços online que realizam essa codificação como o [SpriteBaker.com](http://www.spritebaker.com/), [DataURL.net](http://dataurl.net/#about) ou [Base64-image.de](http://www.base64-image.de/).
- Não entrarei em detalhes, pois esse não é o objetivo da pergunta, mas considere as [vantagens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Advantages) e [desvantagens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Disadvantages) de utilizar essa técnica.

Answer (score 6):

Existem sites para fazer este tipo de encoding.

Um exemplo: http://www.base64-image.de/

Acho que vale a pena referir [**um post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124149/is-embedding-background-image-data-into-css-as-base64-good-or-bad-practice) no Stackoverflow (em Inglês) sobre se é ou não uma boa ideia inserir uma imagem codificada em base64.

Comment: muito obrigado @Sergio era isso mesmo que estava procurando.