# Quando devo usar Data URI?

Tags: html, aplicação-web, data-uri

[Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) [URI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/344/como-inserir-uma-imagem-dentro-de-um-arquivo-css) é aquele recurso que me permite colocar pequenas imagens *inline* no CSS ou HTML para reduzir o número de requisições. É uma alternativa ao CSS Sprite.

Fiz alguns testes aqui e gostei muito do desempenho.

Minha dúvida é quanto a compatibilidade. Posso usar sem medo? Todas os navegadores/plataformas o suportam? Pergunto tanto no desktop como no mobile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Resposta Rápida

Data URI não é suportado no Internet Explorer da versão 5 até à 7. No Internet Explorer 8 existe um limite de 32768 Bytes (32 KB).

Para tudo o resto, não terás problema nenhum de compatibilidade.

## Resposta Elaborada

O uso de Data URI acarreta uma série de preocupações não só referentes a compatibilidade, como performance e manutenção.

Como falaste em CSS Sprite, em baixo segue uma lista de vantagens e desvantagens em relação a Data URIs quando o conteúdo das mesmas são imagens.

## Vantagem

A grande vantagem está na poupança de *HTTP Requests* que quantos menos forem realizados mais rapidamente a página será disponibilizada para o visitante.

Por outro lado, Data URIs não são limitadas a imagens, podem ser utilizadas para muitas outras coisas.

## Desvantagens

- **Compatibilidade**

  Nos dias de hoje não existem grandes desvantagens referentes a compatibilidade, apenas o Internet Explorer nas suas versões mais antigas falha no suporte a Data URI:

  - Data URI não é suportado no Internet Explorer da versão 5 até à 7.
  - No Internet Explorer 8 existe um limite de 32768 Bytes (32 KB) em relação ao tamanho da Data URI em uso.
  - Ao navegar em ligações seguras como HTTPS, uma forma de evitar os alertas de segurança dados pelo navegador devido aos conteúdos seguros e não seguros na página é o uso de Data URIs onde os conteúdos seguem com o documento na ligação segura.
- **Performance**

  O tamanho dos conteúdos fornecidos via Data URI é ligeiramente superior quando comparado com o mesmo conteúdo a ser fornecido através de uma SRC (exemplo das imagens). Isto obviamente trás problemas de desempenho em relação aos downloads que são feitos para disponibilizar a página ao visitante.

  - Peter McLachlan em Julho de 2013 publicou um artigo intitulado:

    [On Mobile, Data URIs are 6x Slower than Source Linking (New Research)](http://www.mobify.com/blog/data-uris-are-slow-on-mobile/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

    No artigo em cima podemos observar que o peso dos conteúdos via Data URI torna-se significativamente mais lento quando temos um uso elevado dos mesmos:

    > ...when measuring the performance of hundreds of thousands of mobile page views, that loading images using a data URI is on average 6x slower than using a binary source link such as an img tag with an src attribute!

    Que traduzido:

    > ... ao medir o desempenho de centenas de milhares de visualizações de páginas para dispositivos móveis, carregar imagens através de Data URI é, em média, 6x mais lento do que um link de fonte binária, como uma tag img com um atributo src!
  - Data URIs não fornecem um nome ao ficheiro, o visitante sofre com este cenário porque não pode guardar a imagem se facultar um nome à mesma.
  - Ao referenciar a mesma imagem diversas vezes, em Data URI estamos efectivamente a ter várias cópias da mesma imagem ao passo que uma imagem via `SRC` pode ser referenciada múltiplas vezes mas só é descarregada e lida uma vez.
- **Manutenção**

  O grande problema no uso de Data URI está na manutenção da página e/ou actualização dos seus conteúdos:

  - Data URIs são difíceis de manter/actualizar quando comparado com a simples substituição de um ficheiro (exemplo de uma imagem).

    Pode-se sempre recorrer a técnicas para lidar com esta questão como é o caso de quem usa PHP para gerar as folhas de estilos (css):

    ```
    <?php
     // data URI da imagem folder16.gif
     echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("../images/folder16.gif"));
    ?>
    ```
  - A cache dos conteúdos via Data URI é a mesma do documento onde os mesmos estão inseridos. Isto obriga a descarregar mais vezes folhas de estilos devido à actualização de imagens, originando um trabalho acrescido no que respeita ao controlo de cache.

---

## Sumário

O uso de Data URI para pequenas imagens ou outros conteúdos estáticos como um icon ou logótipo do site é vantajoso para reduzir o número de *HTTP Requests* optimizando assim a disponibilização da página.

Já para imagens de conteúdos ou outro tipo de informação sujeita a alterações, Data URI vai trazer mais problemas do que soluções sendo preferível disponibilizar os conteúdos na sua forma "nativa".

---

Resposta elaborada recolhendo tópicos chave dos seguintes artigos:

- [Wikipedia Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) - [Advantages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Advantages) - [Disadvantages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Disadvantages)
- [CSS-Tricks: Data URIs](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/)

Comment: Como sua resposta é muito mais abrangente do que eu pedi, estou pensando em mudar a pergunta para algo como **"Quando devo usar Data URI?"**

Comment: Tenho uma dúvida: e quanto a compatibilidade com Androids, iPhones/iPads, Windows Phones, etc... preciso me preocupar?

Comment: @Andrey Dispositivos móveis tem suporte integral para Data URI, sem preocupações nesse campo ;)